# Round Corners in IE10 default mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have been trying to show rounded corners with the default settings in IE 10 don't want to change the document mode and Browser mode:

[image: Screen shot of the result]

I have tried to use .htc from different vendors i.e. css3pie.com, round-border.htc and others too but no result:

```
   <style>
.curved {
 -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 5px #999;
 -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 5px #999;
 behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
 border-radius:0px 0px 5px #999;
 -khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px #999;
 width: 1000px;
    margin: 30px auto;
border-radius: 20px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;

    padding: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

HTML Code:

```
<body>

<div class="curved">
fdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks 
hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj
 fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hd
fdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja 
fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hd
fdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja 
fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hd
fdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja
 fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hdfdhsajk fhdas fhkdsja fhdksj fhdksja fhsdkja fhkdaj fhajks hd
</div>
```

But still no luck... 
Actually problem is I want to use my application on all the browsers and specifically the browser mode and document mode mentioned above in internet explorer.

If i just change my document mode to quirks in IE10 or Standard view it gives me the output. But specifically I want it in this or any other workaround using css or javascript.

I have also tried to forcefully update the document mode and browser mode using meta tag but no help too because it didn't resolve my issues.

Comment: IE has supported border-radius since IE and even if it didn't, you would use the IE10 vendor prefix(-ms-).

Comment: Except there is no `-ms-border-radius` to speak of.

Answer (score 2):

IE has supported rounded corners since version 9, so you shouldn't need the PIE library.

You're also defining the border-radius property twice, this shouldn't matter, but it's good practice to define each property only once.

Also, I notice you are using the `border-radius` property in a non-standard way. The fourth parameter you supply `#999` is invalid, only lengths or percentages are allowed as values. This could be causing IE to ignore that property. Perhaps you mean:

```
border-radius: 0px 0px 5px;
border-color: #999;
border-style: solid;
```

Check out the `border-radius` docs at [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius%29).

Comment: IE should have no trouble distinguishing between an invalid `border-radius:0px 0px 5px #999;` and a valid `border-radius: 20px;` - it simply acts as if the first one wasn't there.

Comment: I don't think this will be the answer because I think you have ignored the bottom of the image in which I have mentioned the document mode and browser mode which is my main concern. And in these mode of IE10 my application is not working. And by default internet explorer starts at these settings...